# sphinx back up one directory

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have followed this [guide](http://www.marinamele.com/2014/03/document-your-django-projects.html) to set up Sphinx.

My directories are as follows:

```
/cms-service
  /documentation
    /modules
     models.rst
```

The guide tells to place the path to the python files in `models.rst`. What should this path be? Clearly `.. automodule:: cms-service.apps.models` isn't working, I keep getting two errors when I run `make html`. **I think I need to go up one directory but I don't know how to do this.**

The errors:

> cms-service/documentation/modules/models.rst:3:
> WARNING: invalid signature for automodule (u'cms-service.apps.models')
>
> cms-service/documentation/modules/models.rst:3:
> WARNING: don't know which module to import for autodocumenting
> u'cms-service.apps.models' (try placing a "module" or "currentmodule"
> directive in the document, or giving an explicit module name)

Any other guides on how to setup Sphinx are welcome too. I've been trying for days...

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cyber,
   I have searched the same blog to carry on the autodoc process with Sphinx and Django. I think there is an error in the tutorial.

In the module/models.rst file, in the tutorial it uses **project.app.models**, in this way Sphinx cannot find the module to process on. However, if you change it to **app.models** it can find your module.

I don't think we need to add project name because it is already specified in the **conf.py**.

Comment: This is not working, I am having the same problems. Can anyone help out?